# Does memcache handle inheritance?

Tags: memcached

I try use memcache to store collection of car and I have a cache name called "carbyIdCache" which returns a car object if ID of a car is passed in. Can I store collection of all sub-class instance of car in "carbyIdCache"? For example, Sedan, Truck, Van and Wagon are subclass of the car. Can instances of Sedan, Truck, Van and Wagon are stored in "carbyIdCache"? By the way, I am using Java. I was asking if memcache handle inheritance. In another word, if it can store objects of different sub-classes.

Comment: Memcache is a simple key-value store, I don't understand what do you mean by inheritance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`memcache` knows nothing about what you are storing in it, it doesn't know about `Java`, or `Python` or `JPEG`s or `MP3`s, it only knows that you gave it an array of `bytes` and they are associated with a `key`.

[Wiki](https://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewOverview)

> The server does not care what your data looks like. Items are made up
>   of a key, an expiration time, optional flags, and raw data. It does
>   not understand data structures; you must upload data that is
>   pre-serialized. Some commands (incr/decr) may operate on the
>   underlying data, but the implementation is simplistic.